# xgboost error: Check failed: !auc_error AUC: the dataset only contains pos or neg samples'

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

I am running the following code without problem:

```
churn_dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data = class_data.iloc[:, :-1], label = class_data.Churn)
params = {'objective' : 'binary:logistic' , 'max_depth' : 4}
cv_results = xgb.cv(dtrain = churn_dmatrix, params = params, nfold = 4, num_boost_round = 1, metrics = 'error', \
                    as_pandas = True)

print(cv_results)
 train-error-mean  train-error-std  test-error-mean  test-error-std
0          0.395833         0.108253            0.375        0.414578
```

However, when I change the metric to 'auc' I get an error message:

```
cv_results = xgb.cv(dtrain = churn_dmatrix, params = params, nfold = 4, num_boost_round = 5, metrics = 'auc', \
                    as_pandas = True)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XGBoostError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-ea99ef0705b5> in <module>()
----> 1 cv_results = xgb.cv(dtrain = churn_dmatrix, params = params, nfold = 4, num_boost_round = 5, metrics = 'auc',                     as_pandas = True)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.py in cv(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, nfold, stratified, folds, metrics, obj, feval, maximize, early_stopping_rounds, fpreproc, as_pandas, verbose_eval, show_stdv, seed, callbacks, shuffle)
    405         for fold in cvfolds:
    406             fold.update(i, obj)
--> 407         res = aggcv([f.eval(i, feval) for f in cvfolds])
    408 
    409         for key, mean, std in res:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    405         for fold in cvfolds:
    406             fold.update(i, obj)
--> 407         res = aggcv([f.eval(i, feval) for f in cvfolds])
    408 
    409         for key, mean, std in res:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.py in eval(self, iteration, feval)
    220     def eval(self, iteration, feval):
    221         """"Evaluate the CVPack for one iteration."""
--> 222         return self.bst.eval_set(self.watchlist, iteration, feval)
    223 
    224 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in eval_set(self, evals, iteration, feval)
    953                                               dmats, evnames,
    954                                               c_bst_ulong(len(evals)),
--> 955                                               ctypes.byref(msg)))
    956         res = msg.value.decode()
    957         if feval is not None:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in _check_call(ret)
    128     """
    129     if ret != 0:
--> 130         raise XGBoostError(_LIB.XGBGetLastError())
    131 
    132 

XGBoostError: b'[14:27:23] src/metric/rank_metric.cc:135: Check failed: !auc_error AUC: the dataset only contains pos or neg samples'
```

It seems that all the predictions are positive or negative.  Am I correct?  Is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem rises when xgboost tries to split to train/validation and in one of the splits it has no negatives or positives examples (either in the train set or the validation set).

**I see 2 quick approaches you can take:**

1. You can check how many positives examples and negative examples you
   have, and get more examples of what you miss. It'll be even **easier and
   faster** for you, to duplicate those examples you lack. For example, if you have a 99% negative examples and 1% positive examples, you might want to duplicate each positive example, 99 times (which is the product of `99/1`).
2. You can create the cross validation yourself, thus, gain control on the split, and force negatives and positive examples for each split.